# Why does my debugger display [LOCAL.8] instead of [EBP-20]

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, disassembly

I have a line in my debugger as follows: `CMP DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.8], 0D`

I more or less understand there's a comparison happening between two values, and I know that `LOCAL.8` in this instance represents EBP-20 (I know this because double clicking the line shows me `CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-20],0D`)

What does `LOCAL` mean?

Comment: Probably a local variable. Which debugger is this?

Comment: OllyDbg. I guess I'm just confused as to why it isn't just displaying EBP-20. Maybe I just need to learn more about local variables- I'm very new to assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local variables are usually referenced relative to ebp (in the standard calling convention with frame pointers retained). Since the stack grows down, local variables are stored below the beginning of the frame, which is "down" from regular memory point of view and "up" from the stack's point of view. Your debugger is trying to be helpful by assuming that any small power of 2 offsets from ebp are references to local variables. The number after the dot represents which local variable it is, assuming 4-byte local variables in a 32-bit environment.

Comment: Thank you. I'll need to do some more learning to fully understand what's going on here- but I've got a better idea of a direction now.